# Using a class inside a structure in the same header file

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to use a class inside a structure like this:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    string b;
    SomeClass some_class;
};

class SomeClass {
private:
    A a;
// some code
};
```

I tried to forward declare the struct but it does not work, I constantly get incomplete type error.

Comment: That can't possibly work. `A` has-a `SomeClass`, which has-an `A`, which has-a `SomeClass`...

Comment: This is impossible - the way you written it, both `A`, and `SomeClass` would require infinite storage space. Forward declaring would help, if you were using pointers - pointer always has a fixed size, regardless of the type its pointing to.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius or references

Answer (score 1):

When you define members of type struct or class as component (and not as reference or as pointer to it), then the memory layout of this component must be defined at this point in time. So, when declaring `SomeClass some_class` within `struct A`, then `SomeClass` must be fully defined including members and so on; and if you declare `A a` as component of `SomeClass`, `A`'s structure needs to be fully defined. Hence, no way to define both as components of each other.

But it's more than a chicken-and-egg question, because - even if you could declare it somehow - what would it mean to instantiate an instance of SomeClass? It would have a component `a`, which would then have a (different) compontent `some_class`, which would then have a (different) component `a`, and so forth.

If I understand you right, you want to build couples of `some_class` and `a`'s. For this, use a forward declaration using `class`-keyword together with a pointer (instead of a nested object). Somewhere in your code, e.g. in the constructor of `SomeClass`, assign a value:

```
struct A {
    int a;
    string b;
    class SomeClass *some_class;
};

class SomeClass {
public:
    SomeClass() { a.some_class = this; };
private:
    A a;
    // some code
};
```